# Weird System.IO error after migrating an asp.net 1.1 application to 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, migration, .net

After migrating an ASP.NET application to 4.0, i get a weird System.IO error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'xxxx' is denied.

Why is this weird..  the server is also running my 1.1 application, also hosted on IIS7, and working with the exact same folder (outside the application). 
NETWORK SERVICE has write access to this folder, and most of all, the 1.1 application just works and doesn't throw the exception.

I'm hosting more 4.0 websites, and never had this problem.

Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: What's the path?  To an aspx file for instance?

Comment: Are the 1.1 application and the 4.0 both running in the same application pool?

Comment: Check your application pools in IIS, what is the account running the pool your 4.0 application is in?

Answer (score 0):

give a full read/write and execute permission in that folder...

Comment: This is a bad idea. While that can be useful as a first diagnostic step to prove that the problem is permissions, it should not be left that way or used as a solution due to the security risk it poses.

Comment: Using a sledgehammer to crack a nut?

Comment: I have granted the Network service full control, and still the same error. This is weird !

Comment: @Jonathan this indicates that your 4.0 site is not running under the Network service account.

Comment: Ok Got it, in the advanced settings of my application pool, the application was set to use the "ApplicationPoolIdentity" not the network service. 
Thanks for the directions!

Answer (score 0):

Does the V4 web application have "AppPool Identity" enabled>

If so you need to ensure the app pool user has appropriate access to the resources (application folder, database, ...) by the app pool identity and not Network Service.

See here for more details on assigning access to app pools. Note, most of the GUI approaches only work on Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 for IIS7.5; with Vista/Server 2008 for IIS 7.0 you'll need to use the command line. With SQL Server you'll need to use SQL statements to create logins/users that map to app pool identities (once created you can use the GUI to assign roles/access.